# App crashes when setting ViewPager adapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Recently I updated my app with 6 languages for users to choose from.
When the app is first opened the user is asked the language preference.
When user selects the language, he/she is greeted with the home screen. Everything works well till there.

Now suppose, user wants to change the language.

**Step 1** :- he/she can go to settings and change. (Problem arises here)

When language is selected from **settings** then user is asked to **restart** the app(either **manually or automatically**).

When app is restarted automatically the app crashes with below log -

**Please Check the Below Logcat**

```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View
> State but received class
> android.support.design.stateful.ExtendableSavedState instead. This
> usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in
> the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/arcMenu1. Make sure other
> views do not use the same id.
```

**Full Logcat Details**

```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View
> State but received class
> android.support.design.stateful.ExtendableSavedState instead. This
> usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in
> the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/arcMenu1. Make sure other
> views do not use the same id.
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2455)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2515)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:154)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1379)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5571)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:745)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:635)
>      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong state class, expecting View State but received class
> android.support.design.stateful.ExtendableSavedState instead. This
> usually happens when two views of different type have the same id in
> the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/arcMenu1. Make sure other
> views do not use the same id.
>         at android.view.View.onRestoreInstanceState(View.java:14811)
>         at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:14786)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3124)
>         at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3130)
>         at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:14764)
>         at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:494)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1486)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
>         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
>         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1238)
>         at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6374)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2418)
```

So I have this home screen(Main Activity) with 6 tabs(in a view pager). One of this tabs has a `Arc Menu`. The log says arc Menu's id has been used at multiple places. I checked and that was not the case.

This error usually happens when I trying to reset the `ViewPager` `adapter` once it has been already set when the app first starts.

`ViewPager`

**Please Check Code For ViewPager code -**

```
 public void setupViewPager(final ViewPager viewPager) {
    
        final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final Resources res = getResources();
    
        if (storageUtil.loadTabs() == null || storageUtil.loadTabs().isEmpty())
    
            adapter.addFragment(new a(), getString(R.string.a), 0);
            adapter.addFragment(new b(), getString(R.string.b), 1);
            adapter.addFragment(new c(), getString(R.string.c), 2);
            adapter.addFragment(new d(), getString(R.string.d), 3);
            adapter.addFragment(new e(), getString(R.string.e), 4);
            adapter.addFragment(new f(), getString(R.string.f), 5);
        
        }
    
    
        if(storageUtil.loadTabs()!=null)
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(storageUtil.loadTabs().size());
        else viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        smartTabLayout.setCustomTabView(new SmartTabLayout.TabProvider() {
            @Override
            public View createTabView(ViewGroup container, int position, PagerAdapter adapter) {
                View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_tab_icon, container, false);
    
                ImageView icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.custom_tab_icon);
                switch (position) {
    
                    case 0:
                        icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.a));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.v));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.c));
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.d));
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.e));
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        icon.setImageDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.f));
                        break;
                    default:break;
                }
    
               return itemView;
            }
        });
    
        if(storageUtil.getHomeTab()==-1)
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
        else viewPager.setCurrentItem(storageUtil.getHomeTab());
        setResideMenuEnabled(false);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
    
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                int x = (int) ((viewPager.getWidth() * position + positionOffsetPixels) * computeFactor());
                scrollView.scrollTo(x, 0);
            }
    
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    setResideMenuEnabled(true);
                    headerTextView.animateText(getString(R.string.a));
    
                } else if (position == 1) {
    
                    headerTextView.animateText(getString(R.string.v));
                    setResideMenuEnabled(false);
                } else if (position == 2) {
    
                    headerTextView.animateText(getString(R.string.c));
                    setResideMenuEnabled(false);
                } else if (position == 3) {
    
                    headerTextView.animateText(getString(R.string.d));
                    setResideMenuEnabled(false);
                } else if (position == 4) {
    
                    headerTextView.animateText(getString(R.string.e));
                    setResideMenuEnabled(false);
                } else if (position == 5) {
    
                    headerTextView.animateText(getString(R.string.f));
                    setResideMenuEnabled(false);
                }
    
          
                    
            private float computeFactor() {
                return (viewPagerBackground.getWidth() - viewPager.getWidth()) /
                        (float) (viewPager.getWidth() * (viewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1));
            }
    
        });
    
        smartTabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);
    
    }
}
```

This issue has been there since the last update of my app. I don't know how or why, suddenly it appeared out of nowhere (has updated android studio though and it had messed up my java files. Android studio wasn't able to recognise any of them as java files).

**P.S - I am not doing any changes in the screen orientation**

Is this happening because when I restart the app, the fragments are not destroyed and are created again?

Any idea what is causing this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53862739/7666442

Comment: Have u read the error `two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. This view's id is id/arcMenu1. Make sure other views do not use the same id.` Your two view has the same id  **`id/arcMenu1`** and its creating the problem

Comment: @NileshRathod Like I have mentioned in question, I have already checked if there is another 'arcMenu1' in the view hierarchy, but there is not. Other layouts have views that use this id but a single layout doesn't have two `arcMenu1`

Comment: I also tried altering the id but same issue.